# Meaning of "How do I get featured?" in context of software development

Tags: phrases, questions

This is my first question at *English Language & Usage* and I'm glad! My English is not so good and sometimes I feel myself very helpless when facing phrases like

> How do I get featured?

What does it mean? I've heard this phrase in Google I/O 2011 presentation and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"To feature" in this context means "to give special prominence to", so "The 2012 Google I/O presentation will feature Kirzilla."

"get" in this context is a slang way of creating a passive-voice construction that isn't so passive.  "To be killed" means something killed you; "to get killed" means to do something stupid resulting in something killing you.

The question means, "What should I do, so as to be *featured* (prominently displayed) in presentations like this one in the future?"

Comment: More accurately, perhaps, "... so that my work will be featured..." depending on context, anyway.

Comment: Seems likely -- they could talk about Kirill's work, or they could have Kirill talk, about his work or about something else; either way, Kirill would "get featured".